# Debug AJAX Requests

Tags: javascript, ajax, debugging

Many time we face issues while working on Asynchronous javascript. We are not sure what request is posted and what respones is obtained.

How to Debug AJAX Requests. Is there a easy way to do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can track each request if you *instanciate a new object* for each call:

```
var oXhr;

    oXhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    oXhr.id = (new Date()).getTime(); /* just an example. It might be flawed if you process requests more than once per ms */

    oXhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (oXhr.readyState == 4 && (oXhr.status == 200)) {
            //do your stuff here
            console.log(this.id);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 6):

The easiest way to see the request and response is as follows:

1. Open the website where you want to inspect request and response in chromw.
2. Click F12 for chrome extention.
3. Click on Network tab.
4. Here you will be able to see all request and response. You will also be able to view how much time is taken by each request.

Comment: Assuming they're using Chrome, of course.

Comment: You may also use other browsers for the same. For instance use Firebug for Firefox.