# Best debug tool to debug Ajax request in PHP

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, json

What is the best debug tool to debug AJAX request in PHP? I want to check whether the method in the **class.php** has been fired when the AJAX function is calling.

Eg:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'classes/MyClass.php/GetItems',
    data: {
        'catgry': cat
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        alert("data recived!");
    },
    error: function (jqxhr, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert("error");
    }
});
```

**MyClass.php**

```
public function GetItems($catgry) {
   $ret = $itmObj->GetItemsByCat($catgry);
   return $ret;
}
```

Comment: Usually the modern day browser comes with built in tools, in chrome you can monitor the network traffic, see the event listeners bound to each dom element, setup break points and step through javascript code.

Comment: The best tool would be an interactive PHP debugger (XDebug) with IDE support.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Debug AJAX Requests](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16970941/debug-ajax-requests)

Comment: Firebug(console) - Mozilla | Developer Tools(Network) - Chrome | Developer Tools - IE

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The simple way is view the trigger in browser itself.

Open the website in chrome browser

- Click F12.
- Click on Network tab. Reload the page to find all the    files
  getting loaded.
- select the MyFile.php and then click on the response tab to    see    ur respone.

You can also see other details like time taken for response, initiator file etc. by this method.

Comment: this doesn't show how to debug line at a time.

Answer (score 6):

As far as I understood the question here is how to debug the PHP code, not the request itself. The request is easily viewable inside the developer tools of your browser. The only one method which I can come with is to add the debugging information into the response to the browser. I.e. to use the response as a feedback.

Comment: http://www.diloc.de/blog/2008/07/10/debugging-php-ajax-applications-with-firephp/ does this - I haven't found anything better

Answer (score 2):

I am using firefox console to see the ajax request. It is good. Even you can use 'Net' of firefox. Both are available by default in firefox.

Comment: i don't think this does line by line debugging into php server side.

Answer (score 2):

The best debug tool for **Firefox** is Firebug. It is an add-on that comes up with Firefox. 
You can add the add-on from the following link.

[Download Firebug](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/)