# alert not working after return back ajax

Tags: php

I send user name and password details to login_page.php through ajax and the same has been  successfully passed on to the login_page.php but after return Alert at the success function which is in the source php not working

```
        $(document).ready(function() {
                $("#submit").click(function() {
                    var $name = $("#name").val();
                    var $password = $("#password").val();
                    $.ajax({

                        type:"POST",
                        url :"http://localhost/school/login_page.php",
                        data:{name:$name,password:$password},
                        /*success:function(data) {  location.reload();}*/
                        success:function(data) { alert("ajax ok"); }

                    });
                });

            });
```

Comment: that's not how you use variable in javascript . var name = $("#name").val(); Without dollar sign. remove those dollar sign

Comment: Try to set also an `error: function()` or use Chrome dev mode to see the network response. Also make sure that `alert` works. Maybe, your browser prevents modals on that page.

Comment: @baskaran   in jquery , after submit click can u get the values of username, password, check it.

Answer (score 0):

This problem might happen due to a number of reasons. The best way to figure out why the program does not behave the way you expect it to is to use CDT (chrome debugging tools), specifically Network debugging, which would help to see what's your request and what the PHP script is actually responding.

Here's a neat blog-post describing a similar use case and how to debug it: http://blog.bcdsoftware.com/2323/how-to-use-chrome-developer-tools-to-debug-ajax/

Comment: I have no error when I execute the same on Chrome or IE11 but I have on  firefox 58.0

Comment: Firefox has debugging tools as well. Check this discussion on the similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18569107/best-debug-tool-to-debug-ajax-request-in-php/18569376

Answer (score 0):

```
 success:function(data) { console.log(data);alert("ajax ok"); }
```

Put console.log in the success function as above and your error should be revealed in the browser console. Also recommend to put error incase the request isnt a success.

```
error: function (html) 
{
 console.log (html);    
}
```