# After filling out the form and clicking submit, the button gets stuck on "sending... but i am receiving the email.. Reusable Form

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have a contact form on my website. After filling out the form and clicking submit, the button gets stuck on "sending..." BUT I still receive the email. I think it might have something to do with the ajax portion of my code? Any help is appreciated.

```
$(function()
{
    function after_form_submitted(data)
    {
        if(data.result == 'success')
        {
            $('form#reused_form').hide();
            $('#success_message').show();
            $('#error_message').hide();
        }
        else
        {
            $('#error_message').append('<ul></ul>');

            jQuery.each(data.errors,function(key,val)
            {
                $('#error_message ul').append('<li>'+key+':'+val+'</li>');
            });
            $('#success_message').hide();
            $('#error_message').show();

            //reverse the response on the button
            $('button[type="button"]', $form).each(function()
            {
                $btn = $(this);
                label = $btn.prop('orig_label');
                if(label)
                {
                    $btn.prop('type','submit' );
                    $btn.text(label);
                    $btn.prop('orig_label','');
                }
            });

        }//else
    }

    $('#reused_form').submit(function(e)
      {
        e.preventDefault();

        $form = $(this);
        //show some response on the button
        $('button[type="submit"]', $form).each(function()
        {
            $btn = $(this);
            $btn.prop('type','button' );
            $btn.prop('orig_label',$btn.text());
            $btn.text('Sending ...');
        });


                    var formdata = new FormData(this);
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: 'handler.php',
                data: formdata,
                success: after_form_submitted,
                dataType: 'json' ,
                processData: false,
                contentType: false,
                cache: false
            });

      });
});
```

Comment: Most probably your `handler.php` returns something that is not JSON and the function `after_form_submitted` can not be called. Use your browser **Developer Tools** to check the *console* and the *network* tab to see JS errors and what exactly PHP returns.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best debug tool to debug Ajax request in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18569107/best-debug-tool-to-debug-ajax-request-in-php)

Comment: `success: function(response) {after_form_submitted(response);}`

Comment: I am not getting any JS error on the console, but still, the button is not showing a success message & instead it is showing submitting.....