# Meteor HTTP package - Request header field is not allowed

Tags: meteor, http-headers

```
url = 'http://api.atompark.com/members/sms/xml.php'
xml = 'some xml'
```

When I use jquery, everything's honky dory:

```
$.ajax({
  method: 'POST',
  url: url,
  data: xml
}).done(function(r) {
  return log(r);
});
```

But when I use HTTP package, I get an error:

```
HTTP.post(url, {
  data: xml
}, function(e, r) {
  return log(r.content);
});

XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://api.atompark.com/members/sms/xml.php. Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

What could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, I need to use `content` instead of `data`

```
HTTP.post(url, {
  content: xml
}, function(e, r) {
  return log(r.content);
});
```

https://forums.meteor.com/t/solved-http-package-request-header-field-is-not-allowed/18460

Comment: Glad you found a solution!

Answer (score 0):

The default ContentType is x-www-form-urlencoded.

Try specifying the content-type within from the call. try the below code:

```
HTTP.post(url, {
    data: xml,
    headers: { "Content-Type": "application/xml"}
}, callback);
```

Comment: It still gives the same error. I don't know, but maybe the receiving api doesnt accept any headers and HTTP package adds some by default. Do you know if I can send empty or no headers?

Comment: if it is xml that you are trying to post, try content type `application/xhtml+xml`

Comment: updated my answer, use `Content-Type` instead of `ContentType`, my typo error :p

Comment: Nope. I guess not content type is allowed. can I not send that header?

Comment: can you debug the ajax request and see what headers or cookies that are being set for the call. To debug, i found an answer on SO here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16970942/1794539

Comment: thanx for help, solution found)